# html form align input fields with check boxes

Tags: html, forms, grid, label, html-input

I have an html form with several input fields that aligned using grid.

```css
div.settings {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  grid-gap:5px;
}
div.settings label { text-align:left;  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold }
div.settings label:after { content: "   "; }
```

```html
  <form id="form_nav" action="/users/new_supplier" method="post"> 
    <div class="settings" style="padding: 2%">
        <label for="sc_suppllier_id">Supllier ID</label> <input id="sc_supplier_id" type="text" />  
        <label for="sc_supplier_name">Name</label> <input id="sc_supplier_name" type="text" style="width: 200%"/>
        <label for="sc_supplier_phone">Phone</label> <input id="sc_supplier_phone" type="text"/>
  </div> 
</form>
```

I would like to put a check box 'Active" on the same line as Supplier ID.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="active"> Active.
```

But can't do it without messing up alignments. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error i got it.

```css
div.settings {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  grid-gap:5px;
}
div.settings label { text-align:left;  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold }
div.settings label:after { content: "   "; }
```

```html
  <form id="form_nav" action="/users/new_supplier" method="post"> 
    <div class="settings" style="padding: 2%">
         <label for="sc_suppllier_id">Supllier ID</label> <a> <input id="sc_supplier_id" type="text"/> <input type="checkbox" id="sc_active"/> <label for="sc_active">Active</label> </a>
        <label for="sc_supplier_name">Name</label> <input id="sc_supplier_name" type="text" style="width: 200%"/>
        <label for="sc_supplier_phone">Phone</label> <input id="sc_supplier_phone" type="text"/>
  </div> 
</form>
```